# How can I use scriptaculous.js with GWT Bootstrap in a GWT project

Tags: gwt-bootstrap

I have been using animation effects from scriptaculous.js in my GWT project. Recently I have added GWTBootstrap library into my project. After that the effects from scriptaculous.js has stopped working. If I disable the following line
"inherits name="com.github.gwtbootstrap.Bootstrap" in my *gwt.xml then it works again. I dont know whether I can use both scriptaculous.js and Bootstrap in same project. Please can someone who used both help me.

Regards
Nava

Answer (score 0):

GWT-Bootstrap uses embedded copies of `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` by default.

If you need to use your own copies or include other resources, you'll need to create a custom `Configurator` and a custom Resources.

For more info with samples click [HERE](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/).